# Laravel collection rename nested key

Tags: php, laravel

How can i rename the key "manufacturer" to, lets say, "test123".

Requirement:

- Not converting the collection to an array.
- Not using DB Query "manufacturer as test123".

collection $stuff:

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#543 ▼
  #total: 14
  #lastPage: 3
  #items: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#541 ▼
    #items: array:5 [▼
      0 => {#447 ▼
        +"id": 30
        +"title": "some nice title"
        +"properties": array:4 [▼
          "price" => "99999"
          "manufacturer" => "Puma"
          "model" => "some model"
          "condition" => "new"
        ]
      }
      1 => {#449 ▶}
      2 => {#448 ▶}
      3 => {#450 ▶}
      4 => {#445 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "https://some-nice-url.com"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
  +onEachSide: 3
  #options: []
}
```

When i use the following code, i change the value of the properties but not the keys.

```
   foreach ($stuff as $key => $value) {
      if(!empty($value->properties)) {
        foreach ($value->properties as $key2 => $value2) {
          if(array_key_exists($key2, $ok))
          {
            $value->properties[$key2] = $ok[$key2]['name'];
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a way without transform. I thought there would be a way to just rename a key. But copy and unset is acceptable, i guess.. Thanks a lot anyway! :)

```
    foreach ($stuff as $key => $value) {

      if(!empty($value->properties)) {

        foreach ($value->properties as $key2 => $value2) {

          if(array_key_exists($key2, $ok))
          {

            $value->properties[$ok[$key2]['name']] = $value2;
            unset($value->properties[$key2]);

          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use maps to do the task of manipulating the collection. I have used macro method to define my own method for collection.

> Collections are "macroable", which allows you to add additional methods to the Collection class at run time. The Illuminate\Support\Collection class' macro method accepts a closure that will be executed when your macro is called.
>    --- [Extending-collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#extending-collections)

---

```
Collection::macro('toChangeManufacturerKeyToTest123', function () {
            return $this->map(function ($value, $key) {
                $value["properties"]["test123"] = $value["properties"]["manufacturer"];
                unset($value["properties"]["manufacturer"]);
                return $value;
            });
        });

$updatedStuff = $stuff->toChangeManufacturerKeyToTest123();
dd($updatedStuff);
```

It is obvious that this will work only for `#items: Illuminate\Support\Collection {#541 ▼` having `Illuminate\Support\Collection` instance

Comment: thanks for your reply. 
it gives me "Error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" on line "$value["properties"]["test123"] = $value["properties"]["manufacturer"];"

this seems furtermore very complicated to just change a key name.

i know collection->transform might work, but i dont know how.

Comment: can you show what is dd($value) inside map function, as the answer will work for collection instance but your collection instance is further inside LengthAwarePaginator instance